# One of my students has a Master's degree but was offered admission to another Master's programme. What could be reason?

Tags: graduate-admissions

One of my former undergraduate students (overseas student), whom I still have contact with, has got a Master's degree from a very, very prestigious US university.

That student recently applied to a lower ranking US university for a PhD program. They send a rejection for the PhD program but offered an admission into their Master's program instead (almost the same field).

What could be reasonable motivation for such an offer? I suspect they didn't read my student's application properly, or it's just rejection that comes with a generic just-in-case offer of paying tuition fees?

Comment: _just rejection that comes with a generic just-in-case offer of paying tuition fees_ Seems like you already know the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Master's programs often charge tuition and they are often profitable.  It is quite possible finances were a factor.

Some universities are greatly reducing PhD admissions owing to lack of money or delays to the graduation of current students because work was disrupted by the pandemic.

Comment: Have you got evidence for the second paragraph?

Comment: @Buffy I saw announcements in the press that some PhD programs would accept nobody this cycle.

Comment: It was too late to trim last year's PhD class when covid hit and it would be shitty to push people out the door after a year of no progress. There just aren't enough funding lines this year. This is gonna be a rough time for people applying in this cycle.